# C++ code compiled on machine 1 can't run on machine 2 because "GLIBCXX_3.4.15 not found"

Tags: c++, compilation

Code is compiled on machine 1 with g++.

Is there a way to compile on machine 1 so that it runs on machine 2 ? Without having to touch/update anything on machine 2 ? I don't have acces to machine 2 ...

Comment: You mean, like the way Windows or Office is shipped on CDs? Compiled at Microsoft, magically runs on your home machine?

Comment: No, I'm asking if everybody is supposed to be GLIBCXX_3.4.15 compatible and if not is there a way I can make my program more portable.

Comment: You can link the C library statically, but that's pretty expensive. There aren't that many different major versions out, so you could provide a small selection of different binaries compiled for different C libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to statically link `libstdc++`,  after GCC 4.5
you can do this

```
    g++ -static-libstdc++ compiler  -o myprogram myprogram.cpp
```

then you can distribute it to machine 2.

Comment: That looks like the kind of answer I am looking for. Does it mean it will include that libstdc++ version in my program ? Anyway, will look into statically linking stuff, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a virtual machine (like with VirtualBox) with the same operating system version as Machine 2 and compile everything with that one to make sure everything (all libraries etc.) is compatible.

Answer (score -1):

It means the `libstdc++` library is not found.

Check the dynamic dependencies on machine 2 and identify the path to the library in question:

```
ldd myprogram
```

Any missing libraries will show up as *"not found."* You need to install the missing packages.